# Utilizing async functions in HTML in Blazor server

Tags: asp.net-core, async-await, blazor-server-side

In one of my Blazor .razor components, I want to utilize an asynchronous function to print a course name given the course's ID in HTML, as follows:

```html
@foreach(var currentID in AllCourseIDs)
{
  <h4>@(await (_dbContext.GetCourseDataByID(currentID).CourseName)</h4>
}
```

and

```cs
private async Task<Course> GetCourseDataByID(int courseID)
{
  return await _dbContext.Courses.Where(c => c.CourseID == courseID).FirstAsync();
}
```

, where `AllCourseIDs` is a List of ints containing the course ID numbers. Each ID # is passed into the database function `GetCourseDataByID`, which finds the entry with the corresponding ID in the database and returns a `Course` class instance. The `Course` class has a `CourseName` member, among others irrelevant in this context.

My problem is that the `await` keyword in the HTML is giving me an error: `The name 'await does not exist in the current context`. I'm wondering what the proper way of going about asynchronous operations in HTML code is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code syntax

```
<h4>@(async ()=> await _dbContext.GetCourseDataByID(currentID).CourseName)</h4>
```